# Custom binary cross-entropy loss with weight-map using Keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, loss-function, unet-neural-network

I have a question regarding the implementation of a custom loss-function for my neural network.

I am currently trying to segment cells for a project and I decided to use a unet as it seems to work quite well. In order to improve my current model, I decided to follow the idea of the original paper of the unet (https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) where they implemented a weight-map assigning thus more weight to pixels that are located in between cells that are tightly associated, as you can see in this picture: [Example of a weight map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQdOU.png).

I am currently using Keras for my unet and my problem is that I do not know how to give my weights to my model without creating any problem. My idea was to create a generator with the images and a 2-channeled array containing the labels in the first channel and the weights in the second channel, that way I can extract my weights and my labels easily in my custom loss function.

My code looks like that:

```
train_generator = zip(image_generator, label_generator, weight_generator)

    for (img, label, weight) in train_generator:
        img, label = adjustData(img, True, label)

        label_weights = np.concatenate((label, weight),axis=3)

        # This is the final generator
        yield (img, label_weights)
```

As you can see, I construct the train_generator with three previously constructed generators, I adjust some things and then I yield my images and combined labels and weights.

Then, when I try to fit my model with fit_generator, I get this error: ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays.

I really do not know what to do and how to implement correctly what I want to do.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You probably need to post more code, like the model architecture.

Comment: I think posting the code for the model would be really too much, it is quite long. However, I follow more or less the same architecture as the model of this person [link](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet).